# Refresh page from server's cache and server meanwhile crashes and is up & running again

Tags: .net, windows, cross-browser, http-headers

If you have a page that is remaining inactive for a long time and because you want NOT to lose the session with server let's say refresh the page every 8 minute. Meanwhile the server crashes let's for 20 minutes. The question is ***what type of refresh*** I have to do into the page so that after an hour if I come back and want to navigate to the page. I assume that server is live again. Is there any type of refresh do that?

Comment: I use  IWebBrowser2::Refresh2() with various types of RefreshConstants.

Answer (score 0):

Why not considering preventing session timeout instead?
See those articles about approaches (asp.net/jquery)
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Keep-Session-Alive.aspxhttp://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article86.aspx